# Give Edit access to Partner Community Login Profile user for their Partner

Tags: community, partner-communities, partner

In application, account is private.  In Salesforce, if account is enabled as a Partner account , then all the Partner user will get the read access to account by default.

However, we have two profile for all Partner User.  1) Partner Admin , and 2) Partner User. 
I want Partner Admin Profile to edit the Partner account and given edit access to their profile.. Even after this , partner admin can't edit access because they don't have record access to it.

Use Case.

Partner Account :   Example Partner

Partner Contact (User) :  User A  - Profile - Partner Admin. Partner admin profile has edit access on Account
Partner Contact (User)  : User B - Profile - Partner User

Now , SFDC will give read access to both Partner User. Partner User can see their partner by default. 
How can I give edit access to Partner Admin profile Users....they are not account owner.  I don't want to write a Apex sharing rule here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use manual sharing.  Here's some steps:

1. Click Sharing
2. Click Add
3. Search Portal Roles and Subordinates by "Company Name".
4. Select "Company Name Partner Admin", and move to the Share With list.
5. Select Account Access Read/Write), you can also control access to Contacts, Opportunities and Cases here.
6. Click Save.

Comment: Yeah.. But, for every partner there is Role. I can't write sharing rules for all the partner. Let Say . Compnay name is ABC , then role ABCsomehting and Company Name is XYZ then role XYZSomthing..   I can't write rules for each and every partner to share records with Partner Admin profile user..

Comment: Are you trying to give Edit access to the Account record or the User record?  Is their one Partner Admin user or one for each Partner Account?

Comment: There will be partner admin for each account who can edit the partner (Account) record.  He will be community user and have edit access of account on his profile.

Comment: For me the easiest way to do this, would be to manually give Edit permission on the Account for the Admin Role for each user.  So XYZ Partner, will have roles for their Partner Users.  XYZ Partner Admin and XYZ Partner User.  While ABC Partner, would have roles ABC Partner Admin and ABC Partner User.  So give Edit sharing permission on the XYZ Partner Account record to the XYZ Partner Admin role.